# How to find the total cost for this python program

Tags: python

I have created a simple python program that lets users drive different cars. The user will enter their full name, address, and phone number. The user will then be asked which car they wish to drive, with a maximum of five selected cars. The cars have set prices and a total bill will be added up at the end of the program, however, I am currently unable to find a solution to work out the total cost for the user. The program also asks the user how many laps of the race they wish to perform in the car, I have already worked out how to display the total cost of the laps, but need it added to the total cost somehow. Thanks!

**Code**

```
cars_list = ["Lamborghini", "Ferrari", "Porsche", "Audi", "BMW"]
cars_prices = {"Lamborghini":50, "Ferrari":45, "Porsche":45, "Audi":30, "BMW":30}
laps_cost = 30
final_cost = []
final_order = {}

cust_num_cars = int(input("Please enter the number of cars you want to drive in this session: "))
while cust_num_cars > 5:
    cust_num_cars = int(input("You can only drive a maximum of five cars! Please try again.\n Enter cars: "))

for index in range(cust_num_cars):
    print("\nChoose a car type from the following list", cars_list)
    select_cars = input("Select a car type: ")
    if select_cars in cars_list:
        print("\nYou have selected to drive the", {select_cars})
        final_cost.append(cars_prices[select_cars])
    if select_cars not in cars_list:
        print("\n",{select_cars}, "is not in the available list of cars to drive!")

cust_name = input("\nPlease enter your full name: ")
cust_address = input("Please enter your full address: ")
cust_phone_num = int(input("Please enter your mobile phone number: "))

add_laps = input("\nWould you like to drive additional laps? (Yes/No): ")
if add_laps == "Yes":
    print("\nYou have selected an additional lap!")
    num_of_laps = int(input("Number of additional laps: "))
    print("\nYou have selected", num_of_laps, "additional laps!")
    final_cost.append(cars_prices[add_laps])
    sum = num_of_laps * laps_cost
else:
    print("\nYou have selected no additional extra laps.")


print("Total laps cost: £",final_cost)
print("\n----Order & Billing summary----")
print("Customer Full Name:", cust_name)
print("Customer Address:", cust_address)
print("Customer Phone Number", cust_phone_num)
print("Total cost", final_cost.append(cars_prices))
```

I have tried everything I know in my little experience with Python to work out a final cost. I have worked out the total cost for the number of laps, but can't work out how to add that to the cost of the selected cars and then display a total cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can't use a for-loop because when you select a car that isn't in the possibilities you have lost an iteration, use a `while` loop

```
# final_cost renamed to car_cost
while len(car_cost) != cust_num_cars:
    print("\nChoose a car type from the following list", cars_list)
    select_cars = input("Select a car type: ")
    if select_cars in cars_list:
        print("\nYou have selected to drive the", select_cars)
        car_cost.append(cars_prices[select_cars])
    else:
        print("\n", select_cars, "is not in the available list of cars to drive!")
```

Then use `sum()` for the cars cost and add to the laps cost

```
num_of_laps = 0
add_laps = input("\nWould you like to drive additional laps? (Yes/No): ")
if add_laps == "Yes":
    print("\nYou have selected an additional lap!")
    num_of_laps = int(input("Number of additional laps: "))
    print("\nYou have selected", num_of_laps, "additional laps!")
else:
    print("\nYou have selected no additional extra laps.")

total = num_of_laps * laps_cost + sum(car_cost)
print("Total price:", total)
```

Comment: okay, I understand the mistake made with that, but where do I define car_cost as it isn't a created variable.

Comment: @Josh sorry, I just renamed `final_cost`

Comment: Thanks so much, this has solved the issue and everything now works as intended. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the total cost, you can use the built-in sum() function, which takes an iterable (like a list) and returns the sum of all its elements. In your case, you can use it to add up all the prices of the cars that the user selected:

```
total_cost = sum(final_cost)
```

Then you can add the cost of the laps to the total cost. In your code, the variable sum holds the total cost of the laps. You can add that to the total_cost variable:

```
total_cost += sum
```

Comment: Any chance you could integrate this into my code, I have attempted what you meant but it didn't seem to work, I probably implemented it incorrectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend in this program its better to add all of your costs in one variable.
in a list your list's elements are not adding together,
but with variables you can add your cost every time you get a cost like this:

```
cost_sum = 0 
cost = input("Enter a cost: ")
cost_sum += cost
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. The cost is meant to be auto-added and not written by the user themselves as the cost is meant to be how much the user will be charged once selecting all options.

Comment: it was an example get the point and use it on your code